# How to bind a Image column in MVC telerik Radgrid

Tags: telerik-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to bind images in Telerik Grid for ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109245/how-to-bind-images-in-telerik-grid-for-asp-net-mvc)

I am using telerik radGrid in MVC3, i want to bind a static image with all the rows.
please help me that how can i achieve this in MVC(Aspx engine).

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.SearchResponse)
           .Name("SearchGrid")
           .Columns(columns =>
               {
                   **//Here I need bind image columnn** 

                   columns.Bound(grid => grid.Name);
                   columns.Bound(grid => grid.CaseNumber);
                 })
               .Pageable(true)
%>
```