# How to bind images in Telerik Grid for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

Please let me know how to bind a image static image with all rows in Telerik Grid for ASP.NET MVC.

```
 <%= Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.SearchResponse)
               .Name("SearchGrid")
               .Columns(columns =>
                   {
                       //Here i need to bind a static image column//

                       columns.Bound(grid => grid.Name);
                       columns.Bound(grid => grid.CaseNumber);
                     })
                   .Pageable(true)
    %>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bind a Image column in MVC telerik Radgrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098436/how-to-bind-a-image-column-in-mvc-telerik-radgrid)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by adding another templated column to your collection:

**Using ASPX**

```
columns.Template(c => { 
%><img alt="Static Image Alt Text" src="<%= Url.Content("~/myImage.jpg") %>" 
/><% 
}).Title("Static Image");
```

**Using Razor**

```
columns.Template(
   @<text>
     <img alt="Static Image Alt Text" src="@Url.Content("~/myImage.jpg") " />
  </text>
).Title("Static Image");
```

**UPDATE:** If you wish to bind images from your model, please refer to the following example:

```
columns.Template(c => {
%>
<img 
alt="<%= c.CustomerID %>" 
src="<%= Url.Content("~/" + c.CustomerID + ".jpg") %>" 
/>
<%
});
```

Or if you're using client templates, try the following:

```
.Columns(columns =>
{
columns.Bound(c => c.CustomerID)
.ClientTemplate("<img alt='<#= CustomerID #>' src='" 
+ Url.Content("~/") 
+ "<#= CustomerID #>.jpg' />")
.Title("Picture");
//omitted for brevity
}
```

Comment: @ArunGupta Do you need any more help with this question?

Comment: Hey Nick, Thanks for your reply, but still i am facing issue with image binding, since i am using partial view and i am paasing image path which is in my local machine that time, its thrwoing error like invalid arguments. could you please post a working code which has bind with any image for MVC ASPX engine.

Comment: @ArunGupta I have added an example with bindings. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yes this is my requirement, but when i am trying this its not bind image, its just displaying column value which is coming from viewModel.

Comment: I added a sample for implementing this using client templates. Try this. You mentioned you wanted a 'static' image, which is why I provided the first few samples.

Comment: What's happening when your grid binds? Are you receiving an error?

Comment: Try referring to a relative directory (such as /DCDOX1/Images/rightside) if possible or adding file:// before the path?

Comment: I need the same thing. Unfortunately I am using in VBhtml. So can you please update your answer which will works for MVC VB.NET 4.0 project. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This way we can bind image with every row.
we can also add Action with these images.

```
columns.Command(commands => commands.Custom("View").ButtonType(GridButtonType.BareImage)
```